# taking session_start() out breaks everything

Tags: php

i'm not exactly sure what the problem is but what i do know is that when i take session_start() out of my code it breaks the whole thing and the email doesn't get sent and the data does not get inserted into the database. But with session_start() being there users are experiencing problems where the email is sent but the data does not get inserted into the database.

Here is my entire piece of code:

```
<?php

$error = "";
$to = "";
$subject = "";
$ForumName = "";
$DriverNumber = "";
$Division = "";
$TruckDriving = "";
$Cargo = "";
$DepotLeaving = "";
$CityLeaving = "";
$CountyStart = "";
$TimeStart = "";
$MileageStart = "";
$DepotArriving = "";
$CityArriving = "";
$CountyEnd = "";
$TimeEnd = "";
$MileageEnd = "";
$CargoDamage = "";
$TruckDamage = "";
$FuelCost = "";
$FuelAmount = "";
$TravelExpenses = "";
$FinesCost = "";
$OnTimeOrLate = "";
$LateFee = "";
$TotalProfit = "";

//GET THE VARIABLES FROM THE FORM ON THE PREVIOUSE PAGE

if (isset($_POST['forum-name']) && $_POST['forum-name'] !== "" && $_POST['forum-name'] !== "Registered Forum Name") {
    $ForumName = $_POST['forum-name'];
} else {
    $error .= "ERROR: You have not entered a registered forum name in your log.Please try again|";
}

if (isset($_POST['driver-number']) && $_POST['driver-number'] !== "" && $_POST['driver-number'] !== "Driver Number") {
    $DriverNumber = $_POST['driver-number'];
} else {
    $error .= "ERROR: You have not entered your driver number in your log.Please try again|";
}

if (isset($_POST['email-address']) && $_POST['email-address'] !== "" && $_POST['email-address'] !== "Email Address") {
    $EmailAddress = $_POST['email-address'];
} else {
    $error .= "ERROR: You have not entered your email address in your log.Please try again|";
}

//var_dump($ForumName);
//var_dump($DriverNumber);

if (isset($_POST['dropdown1'])) {
    $Division = $_POST['dropdown1'];
} 
else{
    $error .= "ERROR: You have not entered your division in your log.Please try again|";
}

//var_dump($Division);


if (isset($_POST['dropdown6'])) {
    $TruckDriving = $_POST['dropdown6'];
} 
else{
    $error .= "ERROR: You have not entered the truck that you drove in your log.Please try again|";
}

if (isset($_POST['cargo']) && $_POST['cargo'] !== "" && $_POST['cargo'] !== "Cargo") {
    $Cargo = $_POST['cargo'];
} else {
    $error .= "ERROR: You have not entered a cargo that you hauled in your log.Please try again|";
}

if (isset($_POST['dropdown5'])) {
    $DepotLeaving = $_POST['dropdown5'];
} 
else{
    $error .= "ERROR: You have not entered a depot that you left in your log.Please try again|";
}

if (isset($_POST['city-leaving']) && $_POST['city-leaving'] !== "" && $_POST['city-leaving'] !== "City Leaving") {
    $CityLeaving = $_POST['city-leaving'];
} else {
    $error .= "ERROR: You have not entered a city that you left in your log.Please try again|";
}

if (isset($_POST['country-start']) && $_POST['country-start'] !== "" && $_POST['country-start'] !== "Country Starting In") {
    $CountryStart = $_POST['country-start'];
} else {
    $error .= "ERROR: You have not entered a country that you left from in your log.Please try again|";
}

if (isset($_POST['dropdown2'])) {
    $DayStart = $_POST['dropdown2'];
} 
else{
    $error .= "ERROR: You have not entered a day that you started on in your log.Please try again|";
}

if (isset($_POST['time-start']) && $_POST['time-start'] !== "") {
    $TimeStart = $_POST['time-start'];
} else {
    $error .= "ERROR: You have not entered a time that you started on in your log.Please try again|";
}

if (isset($_POST['mileage-start']) && $_POST['mileage-start'] !== "" && $_POST['mileage-start'] !== "Mileage Start") {
    $MileageStart = $_POST['mileage-start'];
} else {
    $error .= "ERROR: You have not entered a mileage that you started on in your log.Please try again|";
}

if (isset($_POST['dropdown7'])) {
    $DepotArriving = $_POST['dropdown7'];
} 
else{
    $error .= "ERROR: You have not entered a depot that you arrived at in your log.Please try again|";
}

if (isset($_POST['city-arriving']) && $_POST['city-arriving'] !== "" && $_POST['city-arriving'] !== "City Arriving") {
    $CityArriving = $_POST['city-arriving'];
} else {
    $error .= "ERROR: You have not entered a city that you arrived at in your log.Please try again|";
}

if (isset($_POST['country-end']) && $_POST['country-end'] !== "" && $_POST['country-end'] !== "Country Finishing In") {
    $CountryEnd = $_POST['country-end'];
} else {
    $error .= "ERROR: You have not entered a country that you finished at in your log.Please try again|";
}

if (isset($_POST['dropdown3'])) {
    $DayEnd = $_POST['dropdown3'];
} 
else{
    $error .= "ERROR: You have not entered a day that you finished on in your log.Please try again|";
}

if (isset($_POST['time-end']) && $_POST['time-end'] !== "") {
    $TimeEnd = $_POST['time-end'];
} else {
    $error .= "ERROR: You have not entered a time that you finished on in your log.Please try again|";
}

if (isset($_POST['mileage-end']) && $_POST['mileage-end'] !== "" && $_POST['mileage-end'] !== "Mileage End") {
    $MileageEnd = $_POST['mileage-end'];
} else {
    $error .= "ERROR: You have not entered a mileage that you finished on in your log.Please try again|";
}

if (isset($_POST['cargo-damage']) && $_POST['cargo-damage'] !== "" && $_POST['cargo-damage'] !== "£") {
    $CargoDamage = $_POST['cargo-damage'];
} else {
    $error .= "ERROR: You have not entered a damage cost for your cargo in your log.Please try again|";
}

if (isset($_POST['truck-damage']) && $_POST['truck-damage'] !== "" && $_POST['truck-damage'] !== "£") {
    $TruckDamage = $_POST['truck-damage'];
} else {
    $error .= "ERROR: You have not entered a damage cost for your truck in your log.Please try again|";
}

if (isset($_POST['fuel-cost']) && $_POST['fuel-cost'] !== "" && $_POST['fuel-cost'] !== "£") {
    $FuelCost = $_POST['fuel-cost'];
} else {
    $error .= "ERROR: You have not entered a fuel cost for your load in your log.Please try again|";
}

if (isset($_POST['fuel-amount']) && $_POST['fuel-amount'] !== "" && $_POST['fuel-amount'] !== "Fuel Amount (Litres)") {
    $FuelAmount = $_POST['fuel-amount'];
} else {
    $error .= "ERROR: You have not entered a fuel amount for your load in your log.Please try again|";
}

if (isset($_POST['travel-expenses']) && $_POST['travel-expenses'] !== "" && $_POST['travel-expenses'] !== "£") {
    $TravelExpenses = $_POST['travel-expenses'];
} else {
    $error .= "ERROR: You have not entered a travel expense for your load in your log.Please try again|";
}

if (isset($_POST['fines-cost']) && $_POST['fines-cost'] !== "" && $_POST['fines-cost'] !== "£") {
    $FinesCost = $_POST['fines-cost'];
} else {
    $error .= "ERROR: You have not entered a fines cost for your load in your log.Please try again|";
}

if (isset($_POST['dropdown4'])) {
    $OnTimeOrLate = $_POST['dropdown4'];
} 
else{
    $error .= "ERROR: You have not entered whether you were on time or late in your log.Please try again|";
}


if (isset($_POST['late-fee']) && $_POST['late-fee'] !== "" && $_POST['late-fee'] !== "£") {
    $LateFee = $_POST['late-fee'];
} else {
    $error .= "ERROR: You have not entered a late fee for your load in your log.Please try again|";
}

if (isset($_POST['total-profit']) && $_POST['total-profit'] !== "" && $_POST['total-profit'] !== "£") {
    $TotalProfit = $_POST['total-profit'];
} else {
    $error .= "ERROR: You have not entered a total profit for your load in your log.Please try again|";
}

$body = 
"Name on forum: $ForumName
\nDriver Number: $DriverNumber
\nEmail Address: $EmailAddress
\nDivision: $Division
\nTruck Driving: $TruckDriving
\nCargo: $Cargo
\nDepot Leaving: $DepotLeaving
\nCity Leaving: $CityLeaving
\nCountry Start: $CountryStart
\nDay Start: $DayStart
\nTime Start: $TimeStart
\nMileage Start: $MileageStart
\nDepot Arriving: $DepotArriving
\nCity Arriving: $CityArriving
\nCountry End: $CountryEnd
\nDay End: $DayEnd
\nTime End: $TimeEnd
\nMileage End: $MileageEnd
\nCargo Damage: $CargoDamage
\nTruck Damage: $TruckDamage
\nFuel Cost: $FuelCost
\nFuel Amount: $FuelAmount
\nTravel Expenses: $TravelExpenses
\nFines Cost: $FinesCost
\nOn Time/Late: $OnTimeOrLate
\nLate Fee: $LateFee
\nTotal Profit: $TotalProfit";

if ($Division == "International") {
    $to = "jwtmanagementteam@gmail.com";
    $subject = "$ForumName Log for International";
} elseif ($Division == "Samcro") {
    $to = "jwtsamcrotransport@gmail.com";
    $subject = "$ForumName Log for Samcro";
} elseif ($Division == "Port"){
    $to = "jwtportlogistics@gmail.com";
    $subject = "$ForumName Log for Port'";
} elseif ($Division == "Bio"){
    $to = "jwtbiofuels@gmail.com";
    $subject = "$ForumName Log for Bio-Fuels'";
} elseif ($Division == "WnD"){
    $to = "jwtwagonanddrag@gmail.com";
    $subject = "$ForumName Log for WnD'";
}

//WHO THE EMAIL IS FROM MUST BE A RANDOM OTHER WISE ERRORS HAPPEN
$headers = "From: \"JWT Group\" noreply@jwt-group.co.uk\r\n" . "X-Mailer: php";

//THE mail() SENDS THE EMAIL WITH THE VARIABLES THAT YOU JUST SET ABOVE
if ($Division !== " ") {
    mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
}
//var_dump($to);
//var_dump($subject);
//var_dump($body);
//var_dump($error);

//A MESSAGE TO THE PERSON WHO SENT THE ENQUIRY SENT TO THEIR EMAIL TO SAY THEIR MESSAGE WAS SENT
mail(
        $EmailAddress, "Your log for JWT $Division was sent", "Hi $ForumName
\n Your log for JWT $Division has been received.", "From: \"JWT Group\" noreply@jwt-group.co.uk\r\n" . "X-Mailer: php");

///PHP TO INSERT DRIVER'S BANK DETAILS INTO BANK DATABASE

    $host=""; // Host name
    $username=""; // Mysql username
    $password=""; // Mysql password
    $db_name=""; // Database name
    $tbl_name=""; // Table name

    $un = "";
    $usrname = "";
    $usrpass = "";
    $userID = "";

    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    if(isset ($_SESSION['usrName']))
    {
        $usrname = $_SESSION['usrName'];
    }
    else
    {
        echo "4";
    }

    //var_dump ($usrname);

    if(isset ($_SESSION['usrPass']))
    {
        $usrpass = $_SESSION['usrPass'];
    }
    else
    {
        echo "5";
    }

    $sql="SELECT * FROM jwtdrivers WHERE username='$usrname' and password='$usrpass'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $userID = $rows['id'];

    //var_dump ($userID);

    if($userID == "")
    {
        echo "3";
    }
    else
    {

        $TotalProfitPost = $TotalProfit;
        $LateFeePost = $LateFee;
        $FinesCostPost2 = $FinesCost;
        $TravelExpensesPost2 = $TravelExpenses;
        $FuelCostPost = $FuelCost;
        $CargoDamagePost = $CargoDamage;
        $TruckDamagePost = $TruckDamage;

        var_dump ($TotalProfitPost);
        var_dump($FinesCostPost2);
        var_dump($TravelExpensesPost2);

        $sql="INSERT INTO jwtdriversbank2 (DriverID, LogID, TotalProfit, LateFee, FinesCost, TravelExpenses, FuelCost, CargoDamage, TruckDamage) VALUES ('$userID', COALESCE((Select MAX(LogID) from jwtdriversbank2 tab2 where tab2.DriverID = '$userID'),0)+1,'$TotalProfitPost','$LateFeePost', '$FinesCostPost2' , '$TravelExpensesPost2' ,'$FuelCostPost','$CargoDamagePost','$TruckDamagePost')";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        if($result)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            die(mysql_error());
        }

    }

//POINT BACK TO THE PAGE THAT YOU WERE JUST ON//

// if ($error == " ") {
    // header('Location: ./drivers-log.php');
// } else {
    // header('Location: ./drivers-log.php?error=' . $error . '');

// }
?>
```

And here is where i had session_start() before:

```
///PHP TO INSERT DRIVER'S BANK DETAILS INTO BANK DATABASE

session_start()

$host=""; // Host name
$username=""; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name=""; // Database name
$tbl_name=""; // Table name
```

Sorry if you don't need all of my code but i'm not exactly sure what piece of my code you need but rest assured it was all working fine before apart from the fact that sometimes the email get's sent but the details do not get entered into the database.

Comment: session_start() must be on the TOP op your code, so also ABOVE the comments.

Comment: Have a look at your query. Can you execute it on the DB without problems (not through PHP)?

Comment: Hey Guys I just tried asking a new question but i am getting a message saying that questions are no longer being accepted from my account what can i do about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that happens because you can't use `$_SESSION` without `session_start` you can see the reference [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

you can also set `session.auto_start` to true, reference here [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start)

Comment: try putting it `session_start` at the begging of this script

Comment: tried putting it right at the top just after <?php and i get "[21-Aug-2013 15:40:25 Europe/Minsk] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$error' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\hosting\Dan\JWT\drivers-log-send.php on line 5"

Comment: paste your code in a comment so i can see what's wrong with it

Comment: This is the bit where i've put session_start():

Comment: try putting `;`  after `session_start()` tell me if the problem goes away

Answer (score 0):

To use function `$_SESSION` you need to start a session first, so removing session breaks your code.

Comment: There is no error it's just that the email is sent but the data is not added to the database.

Comment: Just a hunch, not sure, change the variable name for the insert statement, like make $sql as $sql2..